# How can I access a JavaScript file reference (as dll file in .NET) into my D365 FO project?

Tags: integration, x++, dynamics-365, dynamics-365-operations

Now, I have a method in my JavaScript file with a parameter and I have to call that from D365FO x++ and pass an argument. How can I do that?

```
internal final class JavaScriptTestJob
{
    public static void main(Args _args)
    {
         ResourceNode textFileResourceNode = 
         SysResource::getResourceNode(resourceStr(JavaScriptResource));
    } 
}
```